# Cannot assign a value of type 'GeoPoint?' to a value of a value of type 'AnyObject?'

Tags: string, swift

Hi I have this code on view did load:

```
    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geopoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            println(geopoint)

            var user = PFUser.currentUser()


            user["location"] = geopoint


            var query = PFUser.query()
            query!.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:geopoint!)

            query!.limit = 10
            query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (users, error) -> Void in

                var accepted = PFUser.currentUser()["accepted"] as! [String]
                var rejected = PFUser.currentUser()["rejected"] as! [String]

                for user in users {
```

the errors are:

user["location"] = geopoint

Cannot assign a value of type 'PFGeoPoint?' to a value of type 'AnyObject?'

next error is the same on this two lines

var accepted = PFUser.currentUser()["accepted"] as! [String]
                    var rejected = PFUser.currentUser()["rejected"] as! [String]

and is AnyObject is not convertible to '[String]'

and the last error is on the line

for user in users {

'[AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'Generator'
I hope you guys can help me with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need unwrap your optional to access the reference it contains (and call methods on it).

Try this:

```
if let unwrappedUsers = users { for user in unwrappedUsers { ... } }
```

Iff `users` is not empty/`nil`/`None`, its reference will be unwrapped to `unwrappedUsers`.